# Spring boot integrationn smpp: null pointer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to implement spring-boot-integration-smpp, but getting null pointer exception.

integration-context.xml

```
<!--smpp integration-->
<int-smpp:outbound-gateway
        id="smppIntegrationOutboundGateway"
        request-channel="toSMPPChannel"
        source-address="Indosat"
        smpp-session-ref="smppSession"
        reply-channel="fromSMPPChannel"/>

<int:service-activator ref="printService" method="print" input-channel="fromSMPPChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1"/>
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway id="smsGateway" service-interface="com.omexit.niger.smsworker.service.SMSGateway" default-request-channel="toSMPPChannel"/>

<!-- connect to the local broker using the default user name and password -->
<bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${spring.rabbitmq.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${spring.rabbitmq.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${spring.rabbitmq.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="smppSession" class="org.springframework.integration.smpp.session.SmppSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="port" value="xx"/>
    <property name="systemId" value="LBS1"/>
    <property name="password" value="Bsl04n1"/>
    <property name="systemType" value="TCP"/>
    <property name="addrTon" value="INTERNATIONAL"/>
    <property name="addrNpi" value="ISDN"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

send message

```
System.err.println(strMessage);
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(strMessage)
            .setHeader(SmppConstants.SRC_ADDR, "xyz")
            .setHeader(SmppConstants.DST_ADDR, "6285781029162")
            .setHeader(SmppConstants.REGISTERED_DELIVERY_MODE, SMSCDeliveryReceipt.SUCCESS)
            .build();
    String res = (String) smsGateway.send(message).getPayload();
    System.err.println("Res: " +res);
```

Exception:

```
    2018-11-27 14:56:21.414 ERROR [-,,,] 24620 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.smpp.outbound.SmppOutboundGateway#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.mode.indosat.smsworker.SmsWorkerApplication.main(SmsWorkerApplication.java:31) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.integration.smpp.session.SmppSessionFactoryBean$AutoReconnectLifecycle.scheduleReconnect(SmppSessionFactoryBean.java:548) ~[spring-integration-smpp-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.smpp.session.SmppSessionFactoryBean$AutoReconnectLifecycle.start(SmppSessionFactoryBean.java:487) ~[spring-integration-smpp-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.smpp.session.ExtendedSmppSessionAdaptingDelegate.start(ExtendedSmppSessionAdaptingDelegate.java:78) ~[spring-integration-smpp-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.smpp.outbound.SmppOutboundGateway.doInit(SmppOutboundGateway.java:62) ~[spring-integration-smpp-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.onInit(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:94) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:178) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the `SmppOutboundGateway`: we can't start `session` so early from the `onInit()`. Please, raise an issue against https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions project.

Meanwhile as a workaround you can inject a `reconnectingExecutor` property on the `SmppSessionFactoryBean`:

```
<bean id="smppSession" class="org.springframework.integration.smpp.session.SmppSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="port" value="xx"/>
    <property name="systemId" value="LBS1"/>
    <property name="password" value="Bsl04n1"/>
    <property name="systemType" value="TCP"/>
    <property name="addrTon" value="INTERNATIONAL"/>
    <property name="addrNpi" value="ISDN"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="reconnectingExecutor" ref="reconnectingExecutorService"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to add **reconnectingExecutorService**. I have tried the following and its not working:
`@Bean(name = "reconnectingExecutorService")
    public ExecutorService executorService(){
        return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }`

Comment: I added your `SmppSessionFactoryBean` bean definition to my answer with the `reconnectingExecutor` property in the end. Is it clear now?

Comment: I am getting the following error.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smppIntegrationOutboundGateway': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for endpoint 'smppIntegrationOutboundGateway', and no default poller is available within the context.

...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for endpoint 'smppIntegrationOutboundGateway', and no default poller is available within the context

Comment: That’s different story. Your `toSMPPChannel` is a queue and its subscriber can’t be without a poller. Or you should define a global default one. Please, consult with Docs on the matter

Comment: I agree. I already defined global poller and outboundgateway wont accept a poller

Comment: Does it fix your problem? Is it a time to consider accepting the answer to close the discussion for helping others in the community?